# How to include Display and ErrorMessage Decorators to swagger generated documentation

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an API and my models also live there. I'm using .Net core WEB API and swagger. They have decorated fields with Required, ErrorMessage and Display. Such as this:

```cs
[Required(ErrorMessage = "FirstName is mandatory")]
[Display(Name = "Service Name")]
public string RouteName { get; set; }
```

But for some reason when I consume the service the swagger.json file does not have the implementation for the Display or ErrorMessage, it just has the required decorator implementation such that it shows:

```json
"RouteHeader": {
    "required": [ "routeName" ],
```

Is there a way/option to include this from swagger or do I need to convert whatever is coming from swagger and put it into a separate "display model" in order for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Swagger JSON file follows a strict [JSON schema](https://json.schemastore.org/swagger-2.0.json), so you can't really modify its structure without risk of rendering it invalid. You can learn more about the Swagger JSON file specification [here](https://swagger.io/specification/) or about the [JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/).

What you can do is use other properties to include additional information about your model. To extend information provided in the generated schema, implement `ISchemaFilter` interface. It offers an `Apply()` method that is called for each model type (*schema*) that will be included in the result Swagger JSON file. Usually these types are based on request and response types used in controller methods.

```cs
public class ErrorMessageSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        // Skip if schema has no required properties.
        if (!schema.Required.Any())
        {
            return;
        }

        var propertyWithAttribute = context.Type
            .GetProperties()
            .Select(p => (p.Name, p.GetCustomAttribute<RequiredAttribute>()))
            .Where(tuple => tuple.Item2 != null)
            .ToList();

        foreach (var (name, required) in propertyWithAttribute)
        {
            // Will throw for property name of length 1...
            var pascalCaseName = char.ToLowerInvariant(name[0]) + name[1..];

            if (schema.Properties.TryGetValue(pascalCaseName, out var property))
            {
                property.Properties.Add("RequiredErrorMessage", new OpenApiSchema
                {
                    Title = required.ErrorMessage
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The display name filter looks similar:

```cs
public class DisplayNameSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        var propertyWithAttribute = context.Type
            .GetProperties()
            .Select(p => (p.Name, p.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>()))
            .Where(tuple => tuple.Item2 != null)
            .ToList();

        foreach (var (name, required) in propertyWithAttribute)
        {
            // Will throw for property name of length 1...
            var pascalCaseName = char.ToLowerInvariant(name[0]) + name[1..];

            if (schema.Properties.TryGetValue(pascalCaseName, out var property))
            {
                property.Properties.Add("DisplayName", new OpenApiSchema
                {
                    Title = required.Name
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Register the schema filters in startup, in the `ConfigureServices()` method:

```cs
services.AddSwaggerGen(opts =>
{
    opts.SchemaFilter<ErrorMessageSchemaFilter>();
    opts.SchemaFilter<DisplayNameSchemaFilter>();
});
```

##### Result example

Given a simple `Weather` model:

```cs
public class Weather
{
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Temperature is required.")]
    public int Temperature { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Is it cloudy?")]
    public bool IsCloudy { get; set; }
}
```

it will generate this piece of schema in `swagger.json` (some parts removed for brevity):

```
{
"components": {
    "schemas": {
      "Weather": {
        "required": [
          "temperature"
        ],
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "city": {
            "type": "string",
            "nullable": true
          },
          "temperature": {
            "type": "integer",
            "properties": {
              "RequiredErrorMessage": {
                "title": "Temperature is required."
              }
            },
            "format": "int32"
          },
          "isCloudy": {
            "type": "boolean",
            "properties": {
              "DisplayName": {
                "title": "Is it cloudy?"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "additionalProperties": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The result looks rather mediocre in Swagger UI, so feel free to try other properties that could be better displayed in the UI.

[image]

Comment: I was able to do this and it does bring it into swagger json file like you said. The issue still is when I use <ValidationMessage For="@(() => ClassName.CustAccount)">
It still doesn't override the default errormessage. I'm using a blazor server application to pull in the swagger file and the ValidationMessage for that property.

Comment: I just want to override the error message in my blazor project but using the overridden error message that is defined in my middleware coming from swagger

Comment: do you know how to use this coming from a blazor project?

Comment: do you have any idea? thanks